# php select statement dependent on variables existing

Tags: php, mysql, select, if-statement, query-string

I am trying to set up a filter system for a small shop I am developing. Basically, I am working the results off a list of variables. the page, products.php if there is no querystring will show all products. However, if there is a variable present I want it to alter the select statement where necessary.

however, I am having problems filtering. If i use the AND statement for all variables it does not filter appropriately neither does the OR. So if i wanted black size 5 shoes it would show all size fives regardless of color.

Is there a better approach to take with this as is becoming a fair old head scratcher!

```
if ($queryString == NULL){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM store_products 
JOIN store_cat on store_products.cat=store_cat.cat_id 
JOIN prod_sizes on store_products.prod_id=prod_sizes.product_id
JOIN prod_color on store_products.prod_id=prod_color.product_id 
GROUP BY store_products.prod_id";   
}else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM store_products 
JOIN store_cat on store_products.cat=store_cat.cat_id 
JOIN prod_sizes on store_products.prod_id=prod_sizes.product_id
JOIN prod_color on store_products.prod_id=prod_color.product_id 
where store_products.sale='$sale' OR prod_color.color='$color' OR prod_sizes.size='$size' OR store_products.cat='$cat' GROUP BY store_products.prod_id";
}
```

example variable string

```
products.php?sale=&cat_id=1&size=&color=Yellow
```

Comment: you should note that if the first OR condition is true then it doesn't compare further . and also you have to compare the color and size with an AND condition if you want only specific records to be returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try building your WHERE criteria before running the query.

String:
`products.php?sale=&cat_id=1&size=&color=Yellow`

myfile.php

```
$criteria = "WHERE 1 ";

if (isset($_GET['sale']) {
    $criteria .= "AND tore_products.sale=$_GET['sale'] ";
}
if (isset($_GET['cat_id']) {
    $criteria .= "AND store_products.cat=$_GET['cat_id'] ";
}
if (isset($_GET['color']) {
    $criteria .= "AND tore_products.color=$_GET['color'] ";
}
```

And so on then run your query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM store_products 
JOIN store_cat on store_products.cat=store_cat.cat_id 
JOIN prod_sizes on store_products.prod_id=prod_sizes.product_id
JOIN prod_color on store_products.prod_id=prod_color.product_id
$criteria
GROUP BY store_products.prod_id";
```

And please **remember to clean your $_GET variables prior to querying with them**  using `mysql_real_escape_string`, `mysqli` or `PDO`!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM store_products 
    JOIN store_cat on store_products.cat=store_cat.cat_id 
    JOIN prod_sizes on store_products.prod_id=prod_sizes.product_id
    JOIN prod_color on store_products.prod_id=prod_color.product_id ";

if {$queryString != NULL){
$query .= " WHERE tore_products.sale='$sale' OR prod_color.color='$color' OR prod_sizes.size='$size' OR store_products.cat='$cat'"
}
$query .=" GROUP BY store_products.prod_id;"
```

Then you execute your Query :)